# How to list used/unused native libraries from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, clr, pinvoke

I have a .net (4.7.2) application that calls into a 3rd party native library using `[DllImport("Foo.dll"...)]`. That native `Foo.dll` is written in C++ and has a lot of dependencies: 90 assemblies, 360 MB (!) are shipped currently. I know that some dependencies are shipped, but not used anymore. Asking that 3rd party for cleanup had no effect, its getting more and more every few month.

Q: Is there any way to distinguish required, actively loaded *native* assemblies from dll bloat?

I have experimented with `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` on application exit, but it one only returns *managed* assemblies.
I have experimented with `DependencyWalker` and its modern brother [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), but it seems most of the truly required dependencies of `Foo.dll` are loaded on demand - only a small fraction shows up in those apps.

Comment: Perhaps ProcessExplorer would be of use? It should be able to list all dlls loaded by a process.

Comment: Process Explorer is not a good option. Since DLL's are by definition dynamically loaded, you run the risk of hitting an edge case during runtime resulting in a missing library.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to track assemblies being dynamically loaded.

But if some assemblies are only loaded if the feature is in the use, then you don't have any other choice than looking at the code (if you can) or go through *all* the possible code paths and track all loaded dlls.